# Angular 2 - Data model for UI

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a datamodel which common for ui as well as backend, the problem I have is ui needs some additional fields just because I have to show them up.

If I use the same data model for ui and backend, the fields that are being used only UI also will be sent to the backend when I make post request.

Is there any way I can work around this, so that ui specific model data will not be sent to the backend.

Comment: why don't you remove the unnecessary  fields, before sent to the backend?

Comment: Of course you can. You can send even an anonymous JSON object which contains only the necessary fields. What prevents you from having separate  models?

Comment: I'd just create a local variable in javascript that's a copied version of the original data model as I assume you're using it for populating forms/a config of some kind?

Answer (score 1):

You can use different data model for front end and backend. when u will get the response, only that field will be mapped that is in response body.

Similarly, U can send the complete datamodel as request body, and in backend u can map the relevant field and drop the rest.

Comment: Yes, but I thought while sending only, he want to send required fields.

Comment: If thats the case, u can  create a template having the required fields. Like   const template={ field1 :datamodel.field1}  and send the template